# SecurionPay custom integration Checkout via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, payment

I am looking at using SecurionPay to take payments online. However I am finding problems with quite a simple task setting the amount and currency. It seems to keep defaulting.

I am trying to implement the system via JavaScript on and ASP.NET project.

https://securionpay.com/docs/checkout#custom-integration

On the above link it shows exactly how to call up the checkout system (code below exact copy and paste):

```js
<script src = "https://securionpay.com/checkout.js"> </script>
<script src="https:/ / ajax.googleapis.com / ajax / libs / jquery / 3.1.0 / jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="
text / javascript ">
  $(function () {
    SecurionpayCheckout.key = 'pk_test_ZVhCjD2Gz7OF222L00bxIdlD';
    SecurionpayCheckout.success = function (result) {
      // handle successful payment (e.g. send payment data to your server)
    };
    SecurionpayCheckout.error = function (errorMessage) {
      // handle integration errors (e.g. send error notification to your server)
    };
  
    $('#payment-button').click(function () {
      SecurionpayCheckout.open({
        checkoutRequest: 'NTQ1NDAwYTczZTljMjUwYzNhZjA0NTdkOTFjNThiOTY5YzIxY2ViMjBhMDRmOTYwNjg1MDI3OWQ2OTZlN2VjMnx7ImNoYXJnZSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjQ5OSwiY3VycmVuY3kiOiJFVVIifX0=',
        name: 'SecurionPay',
        description: 'Checkout example'
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<button id="payment-button">Payment button</button>
```

However from my side I cannot change the charge or the currency? Any help would be welcome or any examples of an integration of the SecurionPay system on a Web Forms project would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signed CheckoutRequest can be created in two ways:

1. Use dedicated SDK. In your case it would be https://github.com/securionpay/securionpay-net. You should look for SecurionPayGateway.SignCheckoutRequest method.
2. https://securionpay.com/docs/checkout-request-generator

Comment: Is there a way you can sign a Checkout Request yourself to get different prices? I have been looking at this: https://securionpay.com/docs/api#checkout-request-sign but i cant work out how to do it via javascript..

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to sign Checkout Request on your backend and pass it to frontend. You can't do it via javascript directly.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for the help got it setup you got me down the right path

Comment: I have another problem to solve in SecurionPay, since this topic is related i would like to leave link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765865/securionpay-checkout-verify-success
Thanks for any help in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it is the checkoutRequest was my issue:

Basically adjust this string to set a charge and currency.

**checkout-request-generator**

https://securionpay.com/docs/checkout-request-generator