# Securionpay checkout verify success

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, payment

Ok, I decided to use securionpay as a payment method.

What I'm struggling is I don't know how I can verify on my server that the payment was successful

```
<script src = "https://securionpay.com/checkout.js"> </script>
<script src="https:/ / ajax.googleapis.com / ajax / libs / jquery / 3.1.0 / jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="
text / javascript ">
  $(function () {
    SecurionpayCheckout.key = 'pk_test_ZVhCjD2Gz7OF222L00bxIdlD';
    SecurionpayCheckout.success = function (result) {
      // handle successful payment (e.g. send payment data to your server)
    };
    SecurionpayCheckout.error = function (errorMessage) {
      // handle integration errors (e.g. send error notification to your server)
    };

    $('#payment-button').click(function () {
      SecurionpayCheckout.open({
        checkoutRequest: 'NTQ1NDAwYTczZTljMjUwYzNhZjA0NTdkOTFjNThiOTY5YzIxY2ViMjBhMDRmOTYwNjg1MDI3OWQ2OTZlN2VjMnx7ImNoYXJnZSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjQ5OSwiY3VycmVuY3kiOiJFVVIifX0=',
        name: 'SecurionPay',
        description: 'Checkout example'
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<button id="payment-button">Payment button</button>
```

it goes like this

1. user picks a product
2. user clicks order(the request is going to my server where I create signed 'checkout request'
3. I render javascript file with checkoutRequest filled
4. User clicks 'Payment button'
5. user fills card information and clicks Pay
6. SecurtionpayCheckout.success run

whatever 'result' will return to me it doesn't help to verify it on the server. I only generate checkout request on the server side.

My thought is that my server should generate some variable that I would store in order model and 'result' should return me that variable if success then i could verify it otherwise based on what I can verify it ? I propably missing something...

docs:
https://securionpay.com/docs/tutorials/checkout

P.S I don't want to store card information on my server

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [metadata](https://securionpay.com/docs/api#metadata). Put whether data you need in checkoutRequest.charge.metadata attribute. It will be attached to charge and returned in result parameter in success method.

Comment: I think its not a proper way to do at the end of the day. Since checkout request can be decoded from Base64, metadata are exposed so I can't verify it based on it. Instead I would just send back charge_id to my backend and send post to securion to ... This is problem. I don't want to get any info about card used etc. What Im looking for is I guess event. I just want to check if this was success or not. Could you help me ? We can talk in Polish.

Comment: Checkout Request can be decoded but it's signed with your secret key (https://securionpay.com/docs/api#checkout-request-sign) and it can't be modified.

Comment: that's true but when its decoded, metadata with "fake checkout id" could be send back to my to my server, without even sending payment to securion. What I mean is one way or the other I need to send post to securion on backend to verify it completly and then I can use metadata to verify it. Maybe I misunderstand "how I should use metadata". If captured == true it means that client was charged, right ?

Comment: I don't understand how metadata with "fake checkout id" could be send to backend. Metadata attached to checkout request and later to charge is not modifiable on frontend. Typically you would just pass chargeId to backend, there you can retrieve charge and check if it is declined or not. If charge is not found then chargeId is fake. Additionally you can store already processed/verified chargeIds to handle duplications (if someone will try to use previous chargeId). It is impossible to guess chargeId (it has 24 random alphanumeric chars).

Yes, captured == true means that client was charged.

Comment: of course you are right. What I ment is that its impossible to not sending post on backend to check by checkout_id what is status of transaction. I just wanted to to be able to just capture javascript response success and based on this response(only) verify checkout. It could be possible to send just decoded meta data as a confirmation, with fake checkout id and that would be possible If on my backend I wouldnt post checkout_id to securion to retrieve charge. I think we just misunderstanded each other.